# Pandas time series count an event till specific date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm a pandas beginner and I'm using tennis data from https://www.kaggle.com/jordangoblet/atp-tour-20002016 so a data sample will be like this

```
ATP Location    Tournament  Date        Series          Court   Surface  Round  Best_of    Winner       Loser
1    Adelaide    AO         3/01/2000 International    Outdoor   Hard    1st    3          Dosedel S.   Ljubicic I.
1    Adelaide    AO         3/01/2000 International    Outdoor   Hard    1st    3          Enqvist T.   Clement A
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEPuI.png)
and I'm trying to  generate features like :

- how many matches they played each other till current date
- how many matches every player has won against each other till current date
- etc

  I tried basic groupbys and resampling but couldn't reach to the desired solution

Comment: please paste sample data directly as text, it saves us some typing. Also, please post expected output for that sample

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan gotcha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try slicing your dataframe based on the date variable of the events. Then you can use the `groupby` function on an auxiliary column. To get the auxiliary column:

```
df['aux'] = df.apply(lambda x: '_'.join(sorted([x['Winner'], x['Loser']])), axis = 1)
```

After grouping it, you can use the groups to calculate any kind of statistics on them (like the ones you mentioned).

If you wan to get cumulative statistics for the entire history, you can use the `cumsum` and similar functions on the groups (if you ensure that the data was sorted based on event timestamp).

Please let me know if something is still unclear or you are stuck.

Comment: I'm happy I could help :)